# Android ListView and Swipe Refresh

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView and a SwipeRefreshLayout. Everything is working fine, I can scroll up/down and on the top of the list the refreshing is working too.
But if I select an item from the listview my application show me another fragment. After that I would like to go back to the listview without scroll to the top.
I solved this with save/restore listview state, but if I dont wait 1-2 seconds after I go back to listview and I would like to scroll up the swipe refresh is showing but not srolling up.
If I wait a little bit before I scroll up, everything is ok.
On Android 4.4.2 its not problem. On Android 5.0.2 and 6.0.0 its problem.

Comment: use your list view fragment to pop from fragment manager backstack. and make proper handling of list view data in fragment .

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml code for ListView with Swipe Refresh

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView">
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I have already use this layout. I have a working listview with swiperefresh, but I would like to solve if I select an item and return to the listview dont scroll up to the top, and the swiperefresh is wrokign too :)

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't enough.I think it's your listview and swipelayout are reset,such as setAdapter, when return from fragment.

Comment: When I return to the listview the application automatically refresh the contents of the listview, I dont reset manually these objects, maybe reseted automatically?

Comment: Maybe.I don't where your listview is ,Activity or fragment?

Comment: I use ListFragment

Comment: ListFragment will  invoke onCreateView